# Does gmtime() function take into account leap years?

Tags: c++, datetime, embedded-linux, microcontroller, epoch

I am working on embedded linux and the system/controller time is kept in the form of milliseconds since 1/1/1970. I am trying to use gmtime but can't get accurate results. Any example to convert this time (milliseconds) to real time hours:minutes:seconds:day:month will be helpful.

Comment: It certainly should. An example of the inaccurate results you say you're getting, along with a [mcve] that produces them, would be helpful -- in fact it's essential if you want an answer to your question. (You know that `tm_mday` is 1-based, `tm_mon` is 0-based, and `tm_year` is 1900-based, right?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `civil_from_days` which is derived and explained in detail in Howard Hinnant's [chrono-Compatible Low-Level Date Algorithms](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html#civil_from_days).  This function takes a count of days since 1/1/1970 and converts it into a `{y, m, d}` field.  Once you have that done, you just have to deal with subtracting off the number of days from your milliseconds timestamp to get milliseconds since midnight and then break that down into `h:M:s.ms`.

Here's complete code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdint>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std;
    int64_t t = 1490285505123;       // milliseconds since epoch
    int32_t z = (t >= 0 ? t : t - (1000*86400-1))/(1000*86400); // days since epoch
    t -= z * (1000LL * 86400);       // milliseconds since midnight
    z += 719468;
    int32_t era = (z >= 0 ? z : z - 146096) / 146097;
    int32_t doe = z - era * 146097;
    int32_t yoe = (doe - doe/1460 + doe/36524 - doe/146096) / 365;
    int32_t y = yoe + era * 400;
    int32_t doy = doe - (365*yoe + yoe/4 - yoe/100);
    int32_t m = (5*doy + 2)/153;
    int32_t d = doy - (153*m + 2)/5 + 1;  // day
    m += m < 10 ? 3 : -9;                 // month
    y += m <= 2;                          // year
    int32_t h = t / (1000 * 3600);        // hour
    t -= h * (1000 * 3600);
    int32_t M = t / (1000 * 60);          // minute
    t -= M * (1000 * 60);
    int32_t s = t / 1000;                 // second
    int32_t ms = t - s * 1000;            // ms
    cout.fill('0');
    cout << setw(4) << y << '-' << setw(2) << m << '-' << setw(2) << d
                    << ' ' << setw(2) << h << ':' << setw(2) << M
                    << ':' << setw(2) << s << '.' << setw(3) << ms << '\n';
}
```

Just as an example I've used as input `1490285505123ms`, and the output is:

```
2017-03-23 16:11:45.123
```

This takes leap years into account.  It does not take leap seconds into account.  It is very unlikely that your embedded linux system/controller does either, so it would be incorrect to try and do so.

The above algorithm has a very large range of validity for `t`:

```
-5877641-06-23 00:00:00.000 <= t <= 5880010-09-09 23:59:59.999
```

(+/- 5.8 million years)

If you don't mind restricting the lower limit of `t` to `0000-03-01 00:00:00.000` then you can simplify the computation of `era` to:

```
int32_t era = z / 146097;
```

If you can restrict the lower limit of `t` to `1970-01-01 00:00:00.000` then the computation of `z` can be simplified to:

```
int32_t z = t / (1000 * 86400);  // days since epoch
```

And finally, if you are willing to restrict `t` to this 400 year range:

```
2000-03-01 00:00:00.000 <= t <= 2400-02-29 23:59:59.999
```

Then `era` can become simply:

```
int32_t const era = 5;
```

Fwiw, here is a [high-level date/time library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) leveraging the C++11/14 `<chrono>` library that does the exact same computations, just with cleaner syntax.  Your std::lib would have to support `<chrono>` to use this library:

```
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    cout << sys_time<milliseconds>(1490285505123ms) << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not only does `gmtime()` support leap years, it also accounts for **leap seconds**, which is why it's `tm_sec` field's range is defined as [0..60] inclusive.

Comment: According to the `C` standard, `gmtime()` is not _required_ to account for leap seconds, but it is allowed to.  This characteristic is left unspecified.  According to POSIX, `gmtime()` does _not_ account for leap seconds because `time_t` does _not_ include them in its count from 1970-01-01T00:00:00 UTC.  Subsequently, few, if any, implementations of `gmtime()` account for leap seconds (I know of none).  Leap years, yes.  Leap seconds, no.  Though you are correct about `tm_sec`'s range.  In that respect, `struct tm` can represent a leap second, just `time_t` can not.

Comment: @HowardHinnant Whether `time_t` includes leap seconds on Linux and FreeBSD (probably others too) is configurable. When it does include leap seconds, their `gmtime()` can return a `tm_sec` value of `60`. See http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/622da23fd57dabca

Comment: @hvd:  Nice demo with `putenv("TZ=right/UTC")`, thanks.